# SD Card reader will not see large cards

Tags: pantheon-files

This is a bit of an odd one. If I insert smaller SD cards in the built-in card reader (up to 32gb), they read no problem. However, my 128 card isn't seen at all. It reads fine in Windows. Nothing shows in the files app, and If I open Gnome Disks, nothing shows there either. USB card reader sees the card just fine. So the same card works in USB in Elementary, and it works in the built-in card reader on windows. But not on the built-in reader in Elementary OS. I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: I think this is unlikely to be anything to do with pantheon-files tbh. Maybe a driver problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a driver problem, because like I said, smaller cards read fine. Just the 128 card has a problem, but it reads just fine in the USB card reader. I really don't know what it could be.

Comment: driver for >32 gb require paid driver from m$. sdxc (vs sdhc on 32gb) drive or whatever. did you install elementary with the extra licensed software? i am not so well endowed in the sd-card relm to try. my biggest is 32. if i randomly find a 64gb i'll try. please try manually update this driver if it's possible ... idk how. tl:dr: you are missing sdxc support. idk if you add it with lib file or driver update.